# How to elegantly implement single methods with variable output?

Tags: c++

I am trying to improve my code style.

Sometimes I have methods that do complicated checks or computations and depending on the context of the calling method I need different results from these algorithms. Let's assume that there is one result, that is always needed and it will be the return value of the method. But how to deal with the optional other results? Of course I want to implement my complicated method only once. Therefore I have introduced modifiable reference parameters and depending on some conditions they are overwritten with these additional results.

As a convenience for those contexts where I don't need the additional results, I have introduced overloads that create dummy variables that are passed to the single implementation.

Please see the following simplified example code:

```
#include <iostream>

/**
 * \brief Checks whether everything is okay.
 *
 * \param isCheckedFirstTime if point is not null, it will be overwritten with
 * whether this method has been called for the first time
 *
 * \returns okay or not
 */
bool isOkay(bool*& isCheckedFirstTime)
{
    static bool isFirstTime = true;

    if (nullptr != isCheckedFirstTime)
    {
        *isCheckedFirstTime = isFirstTime;
    }

    isFirstTime = false;

    return true;
}

/**
 * \brief Checks whether everything is okay.
 *
 * \returns okay or not
 */
bool isOkay()
{
    bool* dummy = nullptr;

    return isOkay(dummy);
}

int main()
{
    const bool okay = isOkay();

    std::cout << "Is everything okay?: " << okay << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously I could get rid of a lot of boilerplate code by adding a default value for the parameter `isCheckedFirstTime` like this

```
bool isOkay(bool*& isCheckedFirstTime = nullptr)
```

which is not legal, because I cannot bind a non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue of the corresponding type.

Is there a workaround for that? Or is there another possibility to have only one method doing all the computations without overloads for different outputs and **without** having to declare dummy paramters in the calling code?

One solution I could think of is packing all possible results into one `std::tuple`. Then the caller can use what he wants. But it might have a disadvantage, if calculation of optional results is costly. Then having a condition (like `nullptr != ...`) saves computation time if nobody needs the result.

I am looking forward to your proposals!

Comment: Will `isOkay` ever actually return `false`? If not, then why have it return the value of `isFirstTime` instead? Otherwise I suggest you start thinking more about the requirements of your project, and the design of it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, of course it can return `false`. This is just a simplified example. I did not get the rest of your comment...?

Comment: If the code gets really complicated consider replacing your function with a class, where you have `process` function which returns the status of the algorithm (successful, unsuccessful) and then you can use getters to get additional data.

Comment: @Anže I get your point and for some cases you are definitely right. But also for some cases refactoring computation methods into classes might become very unnatural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is done by returning `std::tuple`.

In your case it will look something like:

```
std::tuple<bool,bool> isOkay()
{
    static bool isFirstTime = true;
    bool isCheckedFirstTime = isFirstTime;

    isFirstTime = false;

    return std::make_tuple(true, isCheckedFirstTime);
}
```

In case when you need to return optional complex object or you don't want to calculate unneeded value, it's better to use `std::optional` if you can use C++17.

```
std::tuple<bool,std::optional<bool>> isOkay(bool needCheckFirstTime = false)
{
    static bool isFirstTime = true;
    std::optional<bool> isCheckedFirstTime;

    if (needCheckFirstTime) {
         isCheckedFirstTime = isFirstTime;
    }

    isFirstTime = false;

    return std::make_tuple(true, isCheckedFirstTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're in doubt whether `isCheckedFirstTime` should be a pointer or a reference, so you made it both. That's just inconvenient.

This might be more expressive:

```
bool isOkay(std::optional<bool>& isCheckedFirstTime)
{
    static bool isFirstTime = true;

    if (isCheckedFirstTime)
    {
        *isCheckedFirstTime = isFirstTime;
    }

    isFirstTime = false;

    return true;
}
bool isOkay()
{
    std::optional<bool> dummy;
    return isOkay(dummy);
}
```

Comment: It is not possible like this: `error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::optional<bool>&' to an rvalue of type 'std::optional<bool>'`. And if you make it a const reference, then you have lost the "input character" of that parameter. Still I get, that I should make use of `std::optional` more often (like also the other answers propose).

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore I have introduced modifiable reference parameters and depending on some conditions they are overwritten with these additional results.

Out parameters should be avoided like plague. If a function produces a result, it should be a part of its return type. So how we figure out such type for your case?

You've suggested a tuple; in this case, a `struct` or a tuple would work well.

> But it might have a disadvantage, if calculation of optional results is costly.

Sure, but there's nothing that says you have to necessarily tie the arguments to the results. A function could take a bitset or similar enumeration telling it exactly what to compute, and return a struct full of `optional` values. The specific will largely depend on the specific case being solved.